# Unable to select Chosen dropdown list with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, jquery-chosen

I am trying to click one of the  tags in a Select Dropdown created with Chosen JQuery library.

```
<select id="languagesSelect" data-placeholder="All languages" style="width: 302px; display: none;" class="chzn-done">


<option value="all">All languages</option>
<option value="en">English</option>
<option value="ar">Arabic</option>
<option value="zh_cn">Chinese (Simplified)</option>
<option value="zh_tw">Chinese (Traditional)</option>

</select><div id="languagesSelect_chzn" class="chzn-container chzn-container-single chzn-container-active" style="width: 302px;" title=""><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="chzn-single chzn-single-with-drop" tabindex="-1"><span>All languages</span><div><b></b></div></a><div class="chzn-drop" style="left: 0px; width: 300px; top: 30px;"><div class="chzn-search"><input type="text" autocomplete="off" style="width: 265px;"></div><ul class="chzn-results"><li id="languagesSelect_chzn_o_0" class="result-selected active-result highlighted" style="">All languages</li><li id="languagesSelect_chzn_o_1" class="active-result" style="">English</li><li id="languagesSelect_chzn_o_2" class="active-result" style="">Arabic</li><li id="languagesSelect_chzn_o_3" class="active-result" style="">Chinese (Simplified)</li><li id="languagesSelect_chzn_o_4" class="active-result" style="">Chinese (Traditional)</li><li id="languagesSelect_chzn_o_5" class="active-result" style="">Hungarian</li><li id="languagesSelect_chzn_o_14" class="active-result" style="">Italian</li><li id="languagesSelect_chzn_o_15" </ul></div></div>
</div>
```

Below is how I attempt to select 'English' from the dropdown list:

```
field_language_select = Select(driver.find_element_by_id('languagesSelect'))
field_language_select.select_by_visible_text('English')
```

However I receive this error:

```
ElementNotVisibleException: element not visible: Element is not currently visible and may not be manipulated
  (Session info: chrome=65.0.3325.181)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.37.544315 (730aa6a5fdba159ac9f4c1e8cbc59bf1b5ce12b7),platform=Windows NT 10.0.16299 x86_64)
```

I TRIED:

- Performing click() on the dropdown and sending down arrow keys followed by enter. I received `WebDriverException: unknown error: cannot focus element`
- Moving to the div of the select tag by actions.move_to_element(div_element) but it didn't change anything.

How do I manage to select an element from that dropdown list?

Answer (score 1):

Chosen works by hiding the real select statement and simulating it with divs.

You need to find the input field where you can send the hint text, and then the div with the list of options. Once you have the list, click on the correct item from that list.

Deleting is similar. You need to find the div that holds the list of options selected and click on the correct item.

Comment: Excellent analysis.

Comment: Can you elaborate this: You need to find the input field where you can send the hint text, and then the div with the list of options. Once you have the list, click on the correct item from that list.

Answer (score 1):

My implementation of this problem in .Net looks like:

```
IWebElement chosenInputElement = Driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(".chosen-choices input[type='text'] "));
chosenInputElement.Click();
chosenInputElement.SendKeys(YourTextToSelect);

ReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> elements = Driver.FindElements(By.ClassName("active-result"));
var itemFound = false;

if(elements.Count > 0)
{
    foreach(var optElement in elements)
    {
        if (optElement.Text == YourTextToSelect)
        {
            optElement.Click();
            itemFound = true;
            break;
        }
    }
}

if(!itemFound)
{
    throw new OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException("Element not found.");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `SELECT` tag, as you've posted the HTML, is currently invisible due to `display: none`. Selenium was designed to not interact with invisible elements. Without a link to the page it's hard to say what the solution is but you need to approach this like a user would... what would a user do to cause that dropdown to be exposed? Once you figure that out, write code that executes those user actions and you should be good.

Comment: This doesn't answers the question. Whatever you have mentioned in your answer is pretty much understandable from the HTML provided by OP but your answer doesn't attempts to solve anything.

Comment: @DebanjanB If it's understandable from the HTML, why did OP ask the question? It's ironic that you stated "Excelled analysis" on another answer when they stated basically the same thing I did with different words. Good thing you don't revenge downvote... on a two-week old answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have got exception for Element is not visible, and for same you have to wait for a moment until element is being ready to locate. You can use `driver.sleep()` or `Explicit Wait` method to locate it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to know first how the element interact with the user.

In Chosen you need to **click** first the input field, and enter your keys in the box provided.

This is how I did it (I'm using .Net)

```
var eleChosen = driver.FindElementById("BodyContent_Element_chosen");
eleChosen.Click();
var eleInput = eleChosen.FindElement(By.XPath(".//input"));
eleInput.SendKeys("First Choice");
eleInput.SendKeys(Keys.Tab);
```